# Weird behavior of Directive Scope when set to true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Am new to Angular and came across this weird behavior of Custom Directive when its scope is set to true. In this condition, AngularJS will create a new scope by inheriting parent scope ( usually controller scope, otherwise the application’s rootScope ). So any changes made in Parent will be reflected to child and vice-versa. This behavior is inconsistent in this [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/suman_jsfiddle/511rzq5n/)

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="schoolApp">

  <div ng-controller="schoolCtrl">
    <h2 ng-click="reverseName()">{{schoolName}}, Click me to reverse school name</h2>

    <h2>Student Name : {{student.firstName}} {{student.lastName}}<br>
            Student Contact Num : {{student.mobileNum}}
        </h2>
    <div>Edit in parent :
      <input type='text' ng-model='student.firstName'>
      <input type='text' ng-model='student.lastName'>
    </div>
    <div my-directive class='directive'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS (Controller n Directive) :

```
var app = angular.module("schoolApp", []);

app.controller("schoolCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.schoolName = 'Oxford Academy';
  $scope.reverseName = function() {
    $scope.schoolName = $scope.schoolName.split('').reverse().join('');
  };
  $scope.student = {
    firstName: 'Chris',
    lastName: 'Johnson',
    mobileNum: 123456
  }
});

app.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: true,
    template: "<strong>Inside Directive Scope</strong>" +
      "<div>School Name is : {{schoolName}}</div>" +
      "Change School name : <input type='text' ng-model='schoolName' />" +
      "<br><br>" +
      "<div> Student Details :</div>" +
      "Student Name : {{student.firstName}} {{student.lastName}}<br>" +
      "Student Contact Num : {{student.mobileNum}}" +
      "<br><br>" +
      "Change Student First Name : <input type='text' ng-model='student.firstName'/><br>" +
      "Change Student Last Name : <input type='text' ng-model='student.lastName'/><br>" +
      "Change Student Contact Number : <input type='text' ng-model='student.mobileNum'/>"
  };
});
```

Issue Scenario : As long as am changing School Name in Controller (Parent Scope) its reflecting in Custom Directive (my-directive) but once i change School Name in Child Scope looks like there is some disconnection. Neither changes in Child Scope are reflecting in Parent nor is vice-versa working now.

But following same steps to Change Student First name or Last name in Controller (Parent Scope) will show up in Custom Directive (my-directive) and Changing Student First name or Last name in Child Scope will reflect in Parent scope. No matter how many iterations of changes you do for Student First name n Last name it works fine.

Can someone tell me what wrong am doing or is there something i need to understand that's working under the hood ?

Comment: Make sure you understand how prototypical inheritance works in Javascript. E.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) is a very interesting read that thoroughly explains why the behaviour described above is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `scope : true` ( Directive gets a new scope )
   There is nothing that Angular is doing here but the weird behavior is because of JavaScript Prototypical inheritance. What will happen when a child is changing `primitive values (string, number, boolean)` on a parent, it will end up creating a copy of the value in the child, and break the inheritance chain. That's the reason when `schoolName` is changed in Directive (Child Scope) **its getting a copy of its own and inheritance chain with Parent is gone for toss**.

But this is not the case **when you change a JS Object** (which is student object attached to $scope in your case), **inheritance chain will remain intact no matter what.**

2. `scope : false` ( Directive uses its parent scope )

On other hand if you had set scope to false, your child would have always used Parent scope and there will never be a chance of breaking the inheritance chain.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Divyesh, that was more than helpful man :) Tried same example other primitive values & felt ur answer was bang-on !

Answer (score 1):

This is because of prototypical inheritance. Your directive inherits the properties of the parent scope which means, directive scope's `schoolName` will have the same value as the parent scope's `schoolName`, and the `student` property will point to the same object as the parent scope's `student` property.

When you change the value of schoolName, you just changing a string property on the scope. When you change the `student.firstName`, you change a string property on an object which referenced from both the parent and the directive scope.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a `$scope.$digest();` in your method `reverseSchoolName` e.g.:

```js
$scope.reverseSchoolName = function() {
    $scope.schoolName = $scope.schoolName.split('').reverse().join('');
    $scope.$digest();
};
```

One advice: don't use `scope: true`. Try to pass every parameter itself e.g. `scope: {schoolName: '=', student: '='}` to get an isolated scope, see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive